# Does a patient have to lie on their back (supine) for an MRI scan?

Tags: mri

Could a patient be on their stomach or side during an MRI exam?

I have had CT scans while on my side and it was no problem. The MRI technician says it is impossible to perform an MRI unless the patient is flat on their back.

Comment: For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your MRI, it's probably very simple: if you're lying on your side, you won't fit in the machine.

There's nothing inherent in the MRI scanning process that requires any particular position.  Rather, the MRI scanner is made as small as possible to improve imaging quality.  The platform the patient lies on occupies the bottom of the imaging area, so a scanner just barely wide enough to accommodate a patient's shoulders or hips when lying back won't be tall enough to fit a patient lying on their side.